# Discord Welcome Channel Message

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I made a discord bot and now I want to make it even more complex and I want the bot to also tell me when a user joins and leave the server in a Channel

I made the code like this and it sends only Welcome but doesn't take the users Name or ID.

Can someone help me with this, please?

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  member.guild.channels.get('channel id').send("Welcome");

});
```

The bot sends the "Welcome" but without telling me the users Name and ID like other bots do.

Comment: You should start by actually writing the code that would make it use the name and ID of new members?

Comment: You already have the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object in the event handler stored in the variable `member`. Since it's of type GuildMember, you can call the `displayName` or `nickname` property to get the user's name. Then a simple string concatenation will show the name in the welcome message

Answer (score 0):

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    member.guild.channels.get('channel id').send("Welcome ${member.user.username} ${member.id}");
});
```